# Generate documentation for multiple classes with the same name?

Tags: phpdoc

I have a webapp that has multiple "Controller" files that all define a class called "Controller". There's a routing script that only includes the proper file depending on the page request, and then instantiates a new "Controller" object.

In generating the phpDoc automatic documentation, only the first "Controller" class gets documentation generated for it, and all other files that define a "Controller" object link to that one definition of "Controller" rather than their own. Is there a way to force phpDoc to create unique documentation for each of the redefinitions of the "Controller" class?

Answer (score 1):

phpDocumentor *can* handle this kind of class name duplication, but only by putting the classes in different "packages".

```
/**
 * MyClass #1
 * @package PackageOne
 */
class MyClass {}

/**
 * MyClass #2
 * @package PackageTwo
 */
class MyClass {}
```

This will result in both classes being documented successfully in the same phpDocumentor execution.